# WCF Receive-Request Communication In C# Aplication

Tags: wcf

I want to use WCF for server to client communication.
Start clinet which will send message to server , ones server receive message its display that message in from of MessageBox Confirmation For Asked Question.
So reply will be Yes/No which sent back to client.

As per result of Yes/No clinet will process ahed ...

How can I achieve above thing in C#.net?

I have read many articles about callback but did not get much idea for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) walks through creating the client & service. The difference is, instead of implementing a calculator, you'll want to implement your code for whatever the service does.

One question, though, why do you want the service to display a yes/no and not the client?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I once wrote a [series of blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2008/07/12/an-overview-of-unit-testing-duplex-wcf-services-and-clients.aspx) that describe how to approach development of Duplex WCF services with Test-Driven Development.